# python add value to a list when iterate the list

Tags: python

```
values = [2,3,4]
for v in values:
    values.append([v,255,255])
```

Why do the statements above never end? I make a mistake in my code. However, I find it will never stop when I execute the code above.

Comment: Why would it end? Imagine you have 3 coins and I ask you to count them aloud. Every time you get to the coin before the last I give you 3 more coins. Will you ever finish to count all the coins?

Comment: @DeepSpace Why would it end? Because they don't have infinite memory, that's why :-)

Comment: @DeepSapce I misunderstand the true meaning of the grammar  ```for ... in ...```  . I print the result. It's beautiful.  In fact, the example you described is not very similar. The append statement is not the same as giving sb 3 more coins. It only appends one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You iterate over an array which you grow as you iterate over it.

First values is `[2,3,4]` then after the first iteration, values is `[2, 3, 4, [2, 255, 255]]` then `[2, 3, 4, [2, 255, 255], [3, 255, 255]]` etc. You should `print` along the iteration to understand it better.

The reason is `append` actually changes the very object you are iterating over. You could try

```
values = [2,3,4]
new_values = []
for v in values:
    new_values.append([v,255,255])
```